# How to include an image in the signature of komaletter?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

The help page of `komaletter::komaletter` states:

> signature Typed signature or image placed below closing.

How can I include an image file in the `signature:` statement within the yaml header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
signature: "\\includegraphics[width=0.3\\textwidth]{Signature.png}"
```